# Filter apps from apps list based on internet permission android

Tags: android

Sorry for this question but i want to filter the apps list with permission name INTERNET

how can i do that ?

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

trying something like this

```
PackageManager pm = context.getPackageManager();
        List<ResolveInfo> activities = pm.queryIntentActivities(intent, 0);


            for (ResolveInfo ri : activities) {
                ApplicationInfoclass info = new ApplicationInfoclass();

                    // Add the non system package to the list

                    try {
                        PackageInfo pInfo = context.getPackageManager().getPackageInfo(ri.activityInfo.packageName, 0);

                    } catch (PackageManager.NameNotFoundException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }

                    info.packageName = ri.activityInfo.packageName;
                    info.name = (String) ri.loadLabel(pm);
                    info.icon = ri.activityInfo.loadIcon(pm);
                    apps.add(info);


            }
```

Comment: Get the `PackageInfo`, not the `ApplicationInfo`, and look at the `permissions` field.

Comment: hello i am calling PackageInfo pInfo = context.getPackageManager().getPackageInfo(ri.activityInfo.packageName, 0);
  only but permission tag has different datatype how to filter with internet any code help ?

Answer (score 0):

```
    PackageManager pm = context.getPackageManager();
    for (ResolveInfo ri : pm.queryIntentActivities(intent, 0)) {
        try {
            PackageInfo packageInfo = pm.getPackageInfo(ri.activityInfo.packageName, 0);
            for (PermissionInfo permissionInfo : packageInfo.permissions) {
                if (permissionInfo.name.equals(Manifest.permission.INTERNET)) {
                    //package has internet permission, do something with it
                    break;
                }
            }
        } catch (PackageManager.NameNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```